# Atribuição em massa no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-eloquent

```
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Sale extends Model

{
   protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vendor');
    }

    public function listSales()
    {
       return $this->all();
    }

   public function create($request)
   {
```

Funciona :

```
    $this->id_vendor = $request['id_vendor'];
    $this->price = $request['price'];
    $this->comission = $request['price'] * 0.085;

    $this->save();
```

Não funciona:

```
     // $teste = $this::create([
    //     'id_vendor' => $request['id_vendor'],
   //      'price'     => $request['price'],
  //       'comission' => '$request[\'price\']' * 0.085,
 //  ]);


    return $this->informationVendor($request['id_vendor']);
}

public function informationVendor($id)
{
    return DB::table('sales')
        ->join('vendors', 'vendors.id', '=', 'sales.id_vendor')
        ->where('sales.id_vendor', $id)
        ->select('vendors.name', 'vendors.email', 'sales.price', 'sales.comission')
        ->get()
        ->take(1);
}
```

}

Comment: Coloque a sua classe

Comment: Engraçado porque você criou um método que já existe? Você esta reescrevendo ele inclusive! A sua classe falta configurar fillable ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já indicando um problema, que é reescrever um método que já existe para fazer uma determinada operação que além do mais é primordial, o método `create` tem a finalidade criar novos registros e não tem a necessidade de criar novamente, utilize o que já existe e ele por si faz o que você precisa que é gerar novos registros.

Em sua classe também faltou `fillable` configurado que é por essa configuração que o `create` utiliza para gravar os dados na tabela:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Sale extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['id_vendor','price', 'comission'];

    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vendor');
    }
}
```

para utilizar é só fazer a seguinte linha de código:

```
Sale::create($request->all());
```

Nesse link [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment) explica que deve ser configurado o `fillable` para utilizar o método `create`.

A classe já tem os métodos implementados, não precisa colocar mais nada por si só ele gera lista, grava informações, faz relações, etc., não precisa fazer nada além disso.

Eu estava olhando o seu código, tem uma multiplicação, então, analise a melhor forma de fazer isso por exemplo, pode ser feito assim:

```
$arr = $request->only(['id_vendor','price']);
$arr['comission'] = $request->get('price') * 0.085;
Sale::create($arr);
```

então, só salientando já pode utilizar todos os recursos e trabalhar com a informação da maneira que quiser, mediante suas regras.

Se ainda quiser criar métodos dentro do model (***não recomendaria***), mas, pode mudando o nome dos métodos, ***por exemplo***: `insert`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Sale extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['id_vendor','price', 'comission'];

    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vendor');
    }
    public function insert($request)
    {
        return $this->create($request->all());
    }
}
```

ai usaria assim:

```
Sale::insert($request);
```

ou

```
$sale = new Sale();
$sale->insert($request);
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent)
- [Eloquent: mass-assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment)
- [Eloquent: inserts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#inserts)